# base Symfony2 route on logged in user id

Tags: symfony, routes

Is it possible to modify the routing based on the logged in user's id?

For example, lets say I have the route "/users/1/comments" to get all comments for user number 1, and "users/1/settings" for their settings.

Is there anyway "users/current/comments" and "users/current/settings" could go to the same endpoints if the logged in users {id} was 1?

I thought of using a listener and redirect, but that's sounds horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I let it go to the same action in the controller as the the numbered {id} values.
ie. users/{id}/comments and users/current/comments both went to:

```
commentsAction($id)
{
    if ($id=='current') {
        $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
        $currentuser = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
        $id=$currentuser->getId();
     }

     // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can base this on the logged in user without specifying its id in the url, so you would have

```
/users/comments
```

which redirects to a controller. In that controller you could just get the user id

```
$this->getUser()->getId()
```

For the 2 routes, you could just link those both to the same action.